# Android Studio - Mi View Pager no se muestra correctamente

Tags: android, android-studio, diseño, viewpager

**Adjunto foto de como se ve mi View pager:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Descripción:**

Estoy diseñando una pantalla gráfica dentro de mi aplicación cuya funcionalidad es MUY similar a los perfiles de **Instagram**:

Un perfil de Instagram tiene (y lo digo resumidamente) un layout en la parte superior con datos como por ejemplo el nombre, seguidores, etc. Debajo de dicho layout está el **View Pager** que es el que contiene las publicaciones (fotos o videos). Todo este perfil está envuelto por un **Scroll View** para poder bajar y ver todo el contenido del perfil que hayamos visitado.

Digo que la funcionalidad que quiero lograr es MUY similar a la de Instagram porque quiero que un Nested Scroll View permita explorar el perfil desde la parte **superior** de datos (nombre,etc.) hasta la parte **inferior** de las publicaciones (fotos, videos).

**¿Cual es mi problema?**

Se ve perfectamente en la imágen arriba de todo. Por algun extraño motivo, mi **View Pager** aparece como si tuviese 0dp, por lo que al ejecutar la aplicación, este es invisible.

**Adjunto el código XML de mi diseño:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fafafa"
android:contentDescription="Ayuda">

   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#8d6e63"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbt_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_back_negro"
                android:tint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:text="Tomás Menniti"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15.5sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_descripcion"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_descripcion_negro"
            android:tint="#000000"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/img_chat"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_chat"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_chat"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_chat"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/constraint_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_chat"
            android:tint="#000000" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_foto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#6d4c41"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/perfil"
            android:layout_below="@id/constraint_bar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_calificacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="★★★★★"
            android:textColor="#006064"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_foto"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_foto"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_foto"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_barra0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_calificacion"
            android:background="#C5C5C5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_barra0">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:background="#fafafa"
                android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#a1887f"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_barra1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#C5C5C5"
            android:layout_below="@id/bar_layout"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_barra1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

      </RelativeLayout>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Alguna idea de por que tengo este error?**

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: Buenas, si moves el viewpager abajo del relative layout ?

Comment: Imposible. El relative layout está dentro del Nested Scroll View, por lo que si hago lo que me decís, el view pager queda en la nada. Aún así lo acabo de probar y no funciona!